# Printing out the Internal Hex of a float

Tags: c++, floating-point, hex, printf, ieee-754

So I thought that I could print the internal hex of a `float` like this:

```
const auto foo = 13.0F;
const auto bar = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&foo);

printf("0x%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX\n", bar[0], bar[1], bar[2], bar[3]);
```

This outputs:

> 0x00005041

But when I look at the debugger, the hex that it is reporting for `foo` is:

> 0x003EF830

Can someone help me understand why this didn't work and what I'd need to do to make it work?

Comment: I guess the weird value you see is _address_ of `foo`, not the `foo` value. Check the debugger output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost got it. I'm not sure what the debugger is displaying but it's not your float. Maybe it's the address of it?

The actual float value is **`0x41500000`**. You can check it here: [IEEE-754 Floating Point Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).
If the link doesn't work you'll have to find the online floating point analyzer/description by yourself.

You did it the right way but you forgot that Intel x86 CPUs (I suppose that your CPU is Intel x86) are **little endian**. That means that higher significance bytes are on higher memory addresses. So you should print out bytes in the reverse order than you're printing them, like this:

```
printf("0x%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX\n", bar[3], bar[2], bar[1], bar[0]);
```

Answer (score 5):

The hex value for the floating point value 13.0f is:

> `0x41500000`

Confirmation:

Take `0x41500000` which is in binary:

> `0100,0001,0101,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000`

which split into 1 bit sign, 8 bit exponent and 23bit mantissa is:

> `0 : 10000010 : 10100000000000000000000`

And we can interpret this using the standard floating evaluation of:

> `-1^s x 1.<mantissa> x 2^(exponent-127)`

as

> `(-1)^0 x 1.101 x 2^(10000010-1111111)`

which is

> `1.101b x (10b)^11b`

which is

> `1.625 x 8`

which is

> `13.0f`

Which means your output is correct (assuming a little endian format)

How you are reading it in the debugger is incorrect